# When UITableView is fully reloaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a control that partially or fully changes content of tableView. After the change occurred, I set a flag `tableViewContentHasChanged`:

```
BOOL tableViewContentHasChanged = YES;
[self.tableView reloadData];
tableViewContentHasChanged = NO;
```

My problem appears in `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`; it is called *after* the table view is reloaded, so my flag is not effective inside that method.

In short: what's the right way to observe when the table has *fully* reloaded, so I could set the flag to `NO`? And, what am i possibly doing wrong?

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of this flag?

Comment: ..the purpose is, i need to update some data in a block property for headerViews when the content (and therefore indexes) change. Obviously, i dont want to do it all the time, only when the change occurres. This is the purpose

Comment: If I were you, I would check the "beginUpdates" and "endUpdates" methods of UITableView. Maybe it's more reliable than reloadData.

Comment: @AviTsadok given the code complexity and number of possible scenarios of my case here, begin/endUpadates is actually not reliable at all. For example, `reloadData` could be called at any time, and changing it everywhere is not a solution. But anyway, thanks

Comment: It is still not clear what the flag is for. After your data model has changed, simply call reloadData, and it will reconstruct the view from the data model. What are you trying to achieve with the flag?

Comment: Make your changes to your data model as a result of the trigger, not as a result (and side effect) of the table view reloading its data.

Comment: @fishinear i dont know how to explain it any clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to handle this is in the data model as others mentioned but if you really need to do this, you can do the following:

According to [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData), only visible sections/cells are reloaded when you call `reloadData`

so you need to know when the last visible header is rendered so you set:

```
  tableViewContentHasChanged = YES;
  [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath: get the last displayed index and store it in a member variable:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  //Your cell creating code here
  UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TryCell"];

  //Set last displayed index here
  lastLoadedSectionIndex = indexPath.section;
  NSLog(@"Loaded cell at %@",indexPath);
  return cell;
}
```

That way when `viewForHeaderInSection:` is called you'll know which is the last header in that reload event:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
  //Create or customize your view
  UIView *headerView = [UIView new];

  //Toggle tableViewContentHasChanged when it's the last index
  if (tableViewContentHasChanged && section == lastLoadedSectionIndex) {
    tableViewContentHasChanged = NO;
    NSLog(@"Reload Ended");

  }
  return headerView;
}
```

Please note that this method will only work if last visible section has at least 1 row.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Mariam. Although i had solved it already same way, and came here to write same answer =). Accepted as correct