# populate section tableview with 2 arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to create app that can display location information in sectional table view (like as below).

```
[section 1]
[row 1 - location information];
[row 2 - location information];

[section 2]
[row 1 - location information];
[row 2 - location information];
[row 3 - location information];
 ...
```

My thought is to create 2 arrays. One is key array for section header. The other array is for table view row. 
In my app, the key array has 3 objects.  The other array has 18 objects.  i.e. there has 3 section headers, and display 6 objects/table view row in each section. How can I populate those informations into section table view correctly.?

Comment: Instead of 2 arrays, you could use 1 array of dictionaries, with keys being the sections, and array of objects for that key - rows.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to create a dictionary, with two objects (which are the arrays).
The key can be the name of the section.

Now, with one object (Dictionary) you have all the information you need.

in the numberOfSections just return [NSDictionary allKeys].count.
in the cellForRow grab the object from the right array according to the indexPath.
In the numberOfRows, just grab the correct array from the dictionary according to the indexPath and return the number of objects.

Comment: ..i thought you were gonna answer my question first :))

Comment: Sorry, I thought that you know how to how implement the data source methods.
I saw someone else gave you code.
Please notify us this was helpful.

Comment: well. i dont know if its appropriate to post such comments on SO, but since we are speaking already.... I do know how to implement datasourse methods. i was speaking about my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130257/when-uitableview-is-fully-reloaded which you commented =)

Comment: Oh, I haven't noticed, sorry :)
Actually, I don't have a solution for you over there...:(

Answer (score 0):

```
//setting number of sections
- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [keyArray count];
}

//setting the title for the section
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *sectionName;
    sectionName = [keyArray objectAtIndex:section];
    return sectionName;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [otherArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Hope this helps you to start...

My suggestion will be use a dictionary. The key being the title of the section and the values being the title of the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to have a single array. You can format your array like this

```
[
    {
        "Title": "Title of section 1",
        "Rows": [
            {
                "Title": "Value 1",
                "SubTitle": "Value 2"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Value 1",
                "SubTitle": "Value 2"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Value 1",
                "SubTitle": "Value 2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

One main array which hold dictionaries of section. Section would have its own data plus array of dictionaries of rows.

If this structure is stored in an array.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   [self.array count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSDictionary *section = self.array[section];
    NSArray *rows = section[@"Rows"];
    retrun [rows count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSDictionary *section = self.array[section];
    return section[@"Title"];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Initialization of cell

    NSDictionary *section = self.array[indexPath.section];
    NSArray *rows = section[@"Rows"];

    NSDictionary *row = rows[indexPath.row];

    NSString *title = row[@"Title"];
    NSString *sutTitle = row[@"SubTitle"];

    //Assign them

    return cell;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still looking for this answer I got it with Swift

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("item", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    var item: Item!

    if indexPath.section == 0{
        item = array1[indexPath.row]
    }
    if indexPath.section == 1{
        item = array2[indexPath.row]
    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = item.name
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    if section == 0 {
        return array1.count
    }
    return array2.count
}
```